# proving tangent bundle of surface is a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am working hard with the problem. I know that I can make abstract patch
$$x^{~}(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)=p_3*x_u(p_1,p_2) +p_4*x_v(p_1,p_2)$$
( $*$ is just a multiplication symbol)

can you help me solving this with differential geometric way? not in topological way.

There are 3 axioms to be satisfied to become a manifold.
1. covering axiom
2. smooth overlap axiom( $y^{-1}○x$ is euclidian diffetentiable and defined on open set where x and y are abstract patches
3. hausdorff axiom. for any p=/ q then there should be patch x and y, where x and y have no common image, each includes p and q.

I know the conditions(above). but I dont know how to approach it. can somebody help me?

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained the formula included in your post. What are the $p$'s? What is $x$? Furthermore, what is it exactly that you're trying to prove? What is your definition of a surface?

Comment: sorry, p is point in the domain of tangent bundle. x is patch to the surface where we pick up the tangent bundle. the previois x~ is abstract patch to the tangent bundle. surface here is 2dimensional manifold!